# Is it posible to perform QueryInterface on behalf of VBScript

Tags: c#, com, interface, vbscript

I'm trying to create a COM class with one method that will cast an object to a specific interface on behalf of VBScript.

This is the method signature I'm using:
`public object GetInterface(object unknown, string iid)`

I thought this would be possible because if the method explicitly declares the return type as :

`public IRequestedInterface GetInterface(object unknown, string iid)`

Then VBScript gets the reference to the desired interface.

So I tried just casting to the interface
`return (IRequestedInterface)unknown;`

Unfortunately, VBScript gets a reference to the default interface instead of the requested interface.

I have tried getting round this by creating a custom marshaller using `ICustomMarshaler`.
I thought this would work because the method `MarshalManagedToNative` returns a `IntPtr`.

Because of this I thought that if i just returned the `IntPtr` to the interface 
`return Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(unknown, typeof(IRequestedInterface));`
it would work. But, obviously, it didn't have the desired effect :(

So does anybody know if it is posible and how you would do it?

EDIT:

I thought it would be helpful to add a concrete example (although it is contrived) to explain why I haven't accepted that VBScript will always get the default interface. I'm still clinging to my hope.

Below you will find the contents of 3 files, 'TestLib.cs', 'Build.cmd' and 'Test.vbs'. These hopefully demonstrate why I still think it 'should' be possible.

Note: I have tested this on Windows XP SP3 (x86).

TestLib.cs

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("64e20009-c664-4883-a6e5-1e36a31a0fd8")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2012.06.*")]

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("EB77C7B1-D1B9-4BB3-9D63-FBFBD56C9ABA")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IPerformQi
{
    [DispId(1000)]
    object GetInterface(object unknown, string iid);

    [DispId(2000)]
    IRequested GetIRequested(object unknown);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("7742BC0A-8719-483E-B1DF-AE9CD9A958DC")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IDefault
{
    [DispId(1000)]
    void SayHello(string name);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("FFF34296-2A06-47D4-B09C-B93B63D5CC53")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IRequested
{
    [DispId(1000)]
    void SayGoodbye(string name);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IPerformQi))]
[Guid("222BB88D-B9FA-4F23-8DB3-BA998F4E668B")]
[ProgId("TestLib.PerformQi")]
public class PerformQi : IPerformQi
{
    object IPerformQi.GetInterface(object unknown, string iid)
    {
        if(iid == "FFF34296-2A06-47D4-B09C-B93B63D5CC53")
            return (IRequested)unknown;

        throw new Exception("Unable to find inteface");
    }

    IRequested IPerformQi.GetIRequested(object unknown)
    {
        return (IRequested)unknown;
    }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IDefault))]
[Guid("174ABED6-3325-4878-89E3-BF8BD1107488")]
[ProgId("TestLib.Test")]
public class Test : IDefault, IRequested
{
    void IDefault.SayHello(string name)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello '{0}'", name));
    }

    void IRequested.SayGoodbye(string name)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Goodbye '{0}'", name));
    }
}
```

Build.cmd

```
"%windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /out:TestLib.dll /target:library /r:System.Windows.Forms.dll TestLib.cs
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" TestLib.dll /codebase /tlb:TestLib.tlb
PAUSE
```

Test.vbs

```
Dim oPerformQi 'As TestLib.PerformQi
Dim oTest 'As TestLib.Test
Dim oTest2 'As IRequested
Dim oTest3 'As IRequested

Set oPerformQi = CreateObject("TestLib.PerformQi")
Set oTest = CreateObject("TestLib.Test")
Call oTest.SayHello("Robert")


Set oTest2 = oPerformQi.GetIRequested(oTest)
'Note: This works
Call oTest2.SayGoodbye("Robert")


Set oTest3 = oPerformQi.GetInterface(oTest, "FFF34296-2A06-47D4-B09C-B93B63D5CC53")
'Note: This does not work
Call oTest3.SayGoodbye("Robert")
```

Using the call `oPerformQi.GetIRequested(oTest)` makes the call to `oTest3.SayGoodbye("Robert")` work. This makes me think you are not limited to just the default interface in VBS.

Perhaps .Net is not capable of returning the specified interface because of an implicit cast on the return value? Ideally I would use generics for this, but as we all know COM does not support genrics.

Under this restriction is there any other way that you can think of to achieve this?

EDIT 2:

I have found that I can achieve this using VB6, below is the code for the class.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetInterface(ByVal oUnknown As Object, ByVal IID As String) As Variant

    Dim oIRequested As IRequested

    If IID = "FFF34296-2A06-47D4-B09C-B93B63D5CC53" Then
        Set oIRequested = oUnknown
        Set GetInterface = oIRequested
    Else
        Err.Raise 1, , "Unable to find inteface"
    End If

End Function
```

I would still like to find a C# version if anybody can shed some light on the subject i would appreciate it.

Comment: There's a high likelihood that this won't work if IRequestedInterface is a non-default interface of the same coclass.  The cast will work but the VBScript interpreter will just QI for IDispatch again and get back the default interface.

Comment: HI. Thanks for your comment. I understand what you are saying, however VBScript can use a non-default interface when the method returning it explicitly declares that interface as the return value. I’ve edited my question due to the feedback I have received so far. I’d really appreciate it if you could have another look in light of my edit. Thanks

Comment: It appears that fact VBScript can use a non default interface was unintentional http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/10/53188.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have multiple `IDispatch`-derived interfaces implemented on a single object, to be accessible from scripting environment you should rather implement `IDispatchEx` and have its methods called once a call from script is taking place.

The problem you are facing is caused by the fact that script queries for your `IDispatch` first, and both your `IDispatch`-derived interfaces return the same "main" `IDispatch` leaving no chance for methods of other interfaces to be accessible.

When VBS host is about to call a method on your object, it first queries `IDispatchEx`. If found, the calls are delivered via `IDispatchEx::InvokeEx` and your COM Class can internally route the call to the proper `IDispatch` implementation, both private or forward to external/inner object.

In case `IDispatchEx` is not found, it looks for `IDispatch` and there you are in trouble because it sees only your "main" interface. That is, the workaround for you is to implement `IDispatchEx`. You can do it either way: implement right on your COM class, or instead create a proxy class to accept scripting calls via `IDispatchEx::InvokeEx` and forward to correct `IDispatch` in your code.

Example: Both `A` and `B` classes implement `IX` and `IY` interfaces, `B` additionally implements `IDispatchEx`. Interface methods are `IX::X1`, `IY::Y1`.

```vb
On Error Resume Next

Set A = CreateObject("Test.A")
WScript.Echo A.X1 ' Success, via IX::Invoke
WScript.Echo A.Y1 ' Failure, A's IDispatch is IX's parent and does not have Y1 method

Set B = CreateObject("Test.B")
WScript.Echo B.X1 ' Success, via IDispatchEx::InvokeEx
WScript.Echo B.Y1 ' Success, via IDispatchEx::InvokeEx
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it made me realise that my original question needed clarifying. As a result I have edited the question to explain my requirement better. From what i have read about IDispatchEx the interface is there to support expando objects.  What i need is to be able to take an existing COM object with multiple interfaces and use them in VB Script.  Let me know if I’m still not making sense :)

Comment: See updated answer above. VBS host asks if you have `IDispatchEx` so if you happen to have one, the host will not even look for your `IDispatch` interfaces anymore and you will be able to handle all method calls, even those you don't really have on interfaces ("dynamic methods").

Comment: Yes, that works as a way around the issue, but I already have a work around.
I really want to know if it is possible to return an arbitrary interface to a VBScript client.  Also I want to know how to do it.  I know I can return a specific interface that is not the default interface but that would involve creating a method for each interface I want to cast to. ...

Comment: If I use the IDispatchEx method I’ll have to create a proxy class for every object that I want to use to get access to other interfaces and this could add extra complexity if the methods have the same name but do different things. For this reason I would rather avoid that approach.

Comment: I prefer it like this - I implement IDispatchEx on the same class with 2+ dispatch interfaces. Then IDispatchEx just locates right IDispatch and forwards the call. Another option is to create a standalone proxy, and it can also be done in a way that just forwards calls, i.e. it can be done once flexible enough to work with different inner objects. Anyway, otherwise VBS just does not see anything but main IDispatch.